# Custom [h]:mm:ss in Excel "out of range" for time data type

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel, visual-studio, epplus

Working on an ETL process to take .xlsx files into SQL Server using C# (Visual Studio 14.0, .NET 4.6), and the EPPlus library (OfficeOpenXml, can't use OLEDB as the source files contain more than the max 255 columns). I have several time columns in the .xlsx files that have a custom [h]:mm:ss format. Experiencing problems loading into SQL, both as time and string data types.

For example, a value displays "14:07:00" in the cell and "2:13:00 PM" in the formula bar. When the SQL destination table data type is time, it throws an exception:

> SqlDbType.Time overflow.  Value '14.00:00:00' is out of range.  Must be between 00:00:00.0000000 and 23:59:59.9999999.

If I change the destination data type to varchar, it only imports "14" and not the rest of the string. It seems to only be recognizing the [h] digits, before the first colon. Not sure if this is relevant, but copying this cell and pasting value within Excel returns 0.59, which converts back to 14:07:00 when I change the cell format back to time. Saving the file as a .csv and opening in a text editor produces "14:07:00".

I looked for variations of this specific problem or issues with importing strings containing colons, but haven't found much insight. Does anyone understand what's happening here? How can I fix this programmatically, i.e. not manually changing the data types in the source?

*edit:

[Here's the time formatting in Excel of the source files:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpy3S.png)

Code to read the .xlsx:

```
public static DataSet ReadExcelFile(string filePath, bool hasHeader = true)
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        using (var pck = new ExcelPackage())
        {
            using (var stream = File.OpenRead(filePath))
            {
                pck.Load(stream);
            }
            int startSheet = 1;
            var ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets[startSheet];
            int totalSheets = ws.Workbook.Worksheets.Count;
            for (int sheetNum = startSheet; sheetNum <= totalSheets; sheetNum++)
            {
                var workSheet = pck.Workbook.Worksheets[sheetNum];
                var sheetName = pck.Workbook.Worksheets[sheetNum].Name;
                DataTable dt = new DataTable(sheetName);
                int totalCols = workSheet.Dimension.End.Column;
                int totalRows = workSheet.Dimension.End.Row;
                int startRow = hasHeader ? 2 : 1;
                ExcelRange wsRow;
                DataRow dr;

                foreach (var firstRowCell in workSheet.Cells[1, 1, 1, totalCols])
                {
                    dt.Columns.Add(hasHeader ? firstRowCell.Text : string.Format("Column {0}", firstRowCell.Start.Column));
                }

                for (int rowNum = startRow; rowNum <= totalRows; rowNum++)
                {
                    wsRow = workSheet.Cells[rowNum, 1, rowNum, totalCols];
                    dr = dt.NewRow();
                    var text = "";
                    foreach (var cell in wsRow)
                    {
                        text = cell.Text;
                        dr[cell.Start.Column - 1] = cell.Text;
                    }
                    dt.Rows.Add(dr); 
                }
                ds.Tables.Add(dt);
            }
            return ds;
        }
    }
```

Code to write to SQL table:

```
public static void WriteTables(string excelFilePath)
   {
       DataSet data = ReadExcelFile(excelFilePath);

       SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(Globals.sqlConnectionString);

       sqlConn.Open();

       foreach (DataTable dt in data.Tables)
       {
           if (dt.TableName.Equals(ExcelSheets.Base))
           {
               SqlBulkCopy sqlBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(Globals.sqlConnectionString);
               sqlBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = sqlTables.Base;

               InsertDataTable(sqlBulkCopy, sqlConn, dt);
           }
           //...iterates through each sheet/table
       }
       sqlConn.Close();
   }
protected static void InsertDataTable(SqlBulkCopy sqlBulkCopy, SqlConnection sqlConnection, DataTable dataTable)
   {
       sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(dataTable);

       dataTable.Rows.Clear();
   }
```

Comment: Forgive the dumb question.  In Excel is it REALLY a date time formatted as time?  One more if I may.  Is the 2:13:00 a typo or does it really show as 2:13?

Comment: you better put your code here to understand more

Comment: If 2012, and in your process, perhaps you can parse the time and use the TimeFromParts() function

Comment: If it is displaying like that in the formula bar vs the cell it sounds like it is a proper number (and not a string).  If that is the case remember that excel stores everything as doubles includeing date/time.  You will likely have to convert the `.Value` to a format that SQL Server will accept.  As @techspider said, post your code and what the file content looks like.

Answer (score 0):

If I explicitly cast the offending columns as times prior to reading the file into the data table, this fixes my problem and the imported columns in the SQL table are time data types.

```
 using (ExcelRange col = ws.Cells["G:G"])
 {
     col.Style.Numberformat.Format = "HH:mm";
 }
```

Still do not understand the underlying reason they're coming in as INT when they appear formatted as [h]:mm:ss in the .xlsx however...